# How should I handle Navigation within ViewPager Fragment with Navigation Architecture Components, and Single Activity Approach

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, androidx, navigation-architecture

Here is my Single Activity Approach:

MainActivity has the NavHost

MainFragment with AppBarLayout, TabLayout, ViewPager, etc.

MainFragment Has 2 (or more) Fragments within ViewPager
 -> {

CustomerListFragment -> will navigate to CustomerDetailFragment

EmployeesListFragment -> will navigate to EmployeeDetailFragment

}

CustomerDetailFragment (has completely different design layout)

EmployeeDetailFragment (it also has completely different design layout)

> *** My Problem is that, How I am going to handle Navigation Between these List Fragments to Detail Fragments with Navigation Architecture Components(androidx)***

Answer (score 1):

Say you are in Fragment A with a ViewPager of Fragment B 
And you try to navigate from B to C

Since in the VieWpager the fragments are not a destination, your graph wouldn't know you are on B.

A solution can be to use ADirections in B to navigate to C

Comment: Don't you lose the viewpager tabs layout if you do it this way?